# Jquery, ajax, json, mysql_query is not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

show_page.php:

```
   <?

 session_start();
  include("includes/function.php");

$static = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fb_pages WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION[user_id]' AND page_value = '1' ") or die(mysql_error());

            while($stat = mysql_fetch_array($static)) {

                    $page = $stat['page_name'];


                            echo json_encode($page);
  exit();

                    }       

ob_and_flush();     
?>
```

and js code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "show_page.php",
dataType: "JSON", //tell jQuery to expect JSON encoded response
success: function(response) {

 $('#page').html(response);
 }
});


 </script>
```

I like show the result in `<div id="page"></div>` .

If run this code, the result is one page, and always one page, but if I delete in show_page.php , exit(); then result is good, show all page, but don't show webpage, I think, then may json.
What this problem??

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** write new code with `mysql_query`. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from PHP. Also, you should be very careful about [properly escaping SQL values](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with nasty [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). You should not be inserting arbitrary data from `$_SESSION` into your queries.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Not sure what you're saying your problem is.  Are you saying it's not giving you JSON?

Comment: The problem is, then don't show all page, just one!
Always one page, but delete exit(), the code, then show all page, but this time don't use jquery, ajax :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exiting in your loop, so it only processes the first row. You need to collect all the results in an array, call `json_encode` on the entire array, and then exit.

```
$page = array();
while ($stat = mysql_fetch_assoc($static)) {
  $page[] = $stat['page_name'];
}
echo json_encode($page);
ob_end_flush();
exit();
```

However, your jQuery does:

```
$('#page').html(response);
```

This expects `response` to be HTML, not an array. You need to change that to a loop that does something with each page name in the response, e.g.

```
$.each(response, function(i, p) {
   $('#page').append($('<div/>', { text: p }));
});
```

Comment: Also, just to add to this `ob_and_flush(); ` doesn't exist, it should be `ob_end_flush()`, or `ob_end_clean()`.

Comment: There's probably no reason to use the `ob_XXX` functions anyway.

Comment: 100% agree, after exiting, it would not attempt to run it, but just so OP is clear.

Comment: If you want help, you'll have to be more specific about what the problem is with my answer.

Comment: Naturally, I want, and changed ob_and_flush() on ob_end_clean(), but so not working. it does not matter if you show a different method, the goal would be to display the result of the php file with jquery and ajax

Comment: If you need to use the OB functions, you have to do it before `exit();`, since the latter ends the script.

Answer (score 0):

this part

```
 $page = $stat['page_name'];


 echo json_encode($page);
```

looks like $page is not array, so you don't need to add json_encode() function. 
Therefore, you don't need dataType: "JSON"

Comment: here is the problem, if I use jquery with no results then you can just run the show_page.php good

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to output multiple INDEPENDENT json strings. This will not work. The code should probably be more like:

```
$data = array();
while ($stat = mysql_fetch_array($static)) {
    $data[] = $stat['page_name'];
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Remember that JSON is basically the right-hand side of a javascript assignment operation. Anything you create as JSON **MUST** be valid javascript, e.g.

```
var foo = json_goes_here.
```

You're doing something like

```
var foo = 'bar''baz';
```

Instead, build an array of strings, which when json-encoded, will be more like

```
var foo = ['bar', 'baz'];
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, with JSON